# How do I load user details from db into memory to personalize my bot

Tags: c#, entity-framework, botframework

My bot is in a web application that requires user authentication using OAuth.  When a user starts a chat session I would like to load the user details into memory to personalize dialogs.  Below is the current way i am doing it, but would like advice from anyone that has better method.

```
private async Task OnMessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var name = GetUserDetails(result);

    var message = await result;

    string id = context.Activity.Id;


    string promptText = $"Hi {name}, before we start which product do you want to chat about today?";

    PromptDialog.Choice(
        context: context,
          resume: ChoiceReceivedAsync,
          options: (IEnumerable<SoftwareOptions>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(SoftwareOptions)),
          prompt: promptText,
          retry: "Sorry please select one of the options I listed thanks.",
          promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto
          );
}
```

The idea is the `GetUserDetails` method loads the details like username, firstname, companyId etc.  I can then call the user details from any dialog as needed when my bot responds to personalise the conversation.

```
private object GetUserDetails(IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var db = new LicensingDbContext();

    string id = "John.Smith";
    var user = (from u in db.AspNetUsers
            where (u.UserName == id)
            select new UserDetails
            {
                FirstName = u.FirstName
            }).ToList();

    return user.First();
}
```

Comment: Firstly, don't use `.ToList()` then `.First()`, just use `.First()` or `.Single()`. `.ToList()` will pull all matching records from the DB. `.First()` applies when "I expect multiple entries, but only care about the first one.", `.Single()` applies when "I expect 1 and only 1 entry." Given a user would be logging into the application I would recommend looking at appending their name & user ID into the Auth Token so that you can retrieve it without going to the database each time.

Comment: Did @steve py's comment fix your issue?

Comment: @StevePy that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private async Task OnMessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity)
{ 
    var userProfile = await LoadUserData(context);

    string promptText = $"Hi {userProfile.FirstName}, before we start what product do you want to chat about today?";

    PromptDialog.Choice(
        context: context,
        resume: ChoiceReceivedAsync,
        options: (IEnumerable<SoftwareOptions>) Enum.GetValues(typeof(SoftwareOptions)),
        prompt: promptText,
        retry: "Sorry please select one of the options I listed thanks.",
        promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto
    );
}

public async Task<UserProfile> LoadUserData(IDialogContext context)
{
    LicenseDbContext db = new LicenseDbContext();

    var userProfile = (from u in db.AspNetUsers
        join c in db.Companies on u.CompanyID equals c.CompanyID
        where u.UserName == "john.smith"
        select new UserProfile()
        {
            UserName = u.UserName,
            FirstName = u.FirstName,
            CompanyId = u.CompanyID,
            ParentCompany = c.ParentCompanyID,
            }).Single();
    return userProfile;
}
```